# Transaction Failed when I try to swap BNB for CAKE using swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens

Tags: uniswap, ethers.js, pancakeswap

I'm trying to swap on Pancakeswap for BNB for CAKE, but I've been running into an error. The error reason says, "transaction failed" code: "CALL_EXCEPTION".  Been at it for a couple of days, but I can't figure it out. May I ask for your help, please?

It eats up my gas, but the transaction fails:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x85be92c54e6a9e7267ca62ae7d149115dfebe0ae9a6cee3a709797710a70847a

Here is my code:

```
async function swapOnPancake(account) {
  const router = new Contract(
    testAddresses.router,
    [
      'function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external',
      'function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
      'function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast)'
    ], 
    account
    );

    path = [WETH_TOKEN_ADDRESS, tokenAddress];
    to = recipient;
    const amountIn = utils.parseEther("0.001");
    // const amounts = await router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, path);
    // const amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(10));

    try{
      const tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        amountIn, 
        0, 
        path, 
        to, 
        Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10, 
        {
          'gasLimit': 2140790,
          'gasPrice': utils.parseUnits('10', 'gwei')
        }
      );
      // console.log(tx);
      const receipt = await tx.wait();
      console.log(receipt);
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting same error - have you managed to find a fix?

Comment: Are you able to provide more code please? Obviously without your private keys

Comment: A couple of things that should consider: 1/ For `swapExactETHForTokensXXXX` to work you need to send ETH/BNB, if you want to send WETH/WBNB use `swapExactTokensForTokensXXXX`, 2/ Javascript `Date.now()` returns millisecons, and solidity expects seconds, 3/ If you use WETH/WBNB make sure to approve the router address for the amount used.

Answer (score 1):

try below.  The functions of ExactETH vs Tokens are different.

```
  const tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    0, 
    path, 
    to, 
    Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10, 
    {
      'value': amountIn,
      'gasLimit': 2140790,
      'gasPrice': utils.parseUnits('10', 'gwei')
    }
  );
```

Comment: Be aware that `Date.now()` returns milliseconds and the deadline parameters is in seconds.